# Pidyon in the case of Siamese birth

Tags: halacha, medicine, pidyon-haben

Let's say that two boys came out co-joined. There is technically no single "first born" since they both exited together.

If they remain co-joined for 30 days, do they both get redeemed?

If they were separated prior to 30 days, which one is considered the "bechor" who has to be redeemed, or do they both get redeemed in this case, also?

Comment: http://ohr.edu/ask_db/ask_main.php/104/Q1/

Comment: [Thanks](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/53606/5323), @user6591 :)

Comment: @Shokhet my pleasure:)

Answer (score 5):

As per [Menachos 37a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=30&daf=37&format=pdf), the payment is five sela'im per head.

> בעא מיניה פלימו מרבי מי שיש לו שני ראשים באיזה מהן מניח תפילין א''ל או
>   קום גלי או קבל עלך שמתא אדהכי אתא ההוא גברא א''ל איתיליד לי ינוקא דאית
>   ליה תרי רישי כמה בעינן למיתב לכהן אתא ההוא סבא תנא ליה חייב ליתן לו י'
>   סלעים
>
> Phlimo asked Rebbi (Yehudah Hanassi): "If someone has two heads, which
>   one does he put tefillin on?" Rebbi told him "Either leave, or I'll
>   put you into *cherem*."* At that moment, a man came to them and said
>   "I just had a baby that has two heads! How much do I need to give to
>   the kohen (for the *pidyon*)?" One old man came, and taught (תנא) --
>   you must give ten *sela'im*.

(*my translation*)

The gemara then proceeds to prove that this is the case (*the discussion spills over to [side b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=30&daf=37b&format=pdf)*).

No mention is made of separating these children, as far as I could tell.

Kudos to user6591 for [pointing out](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/53600/pidyon-in-the-case-of-siamese-birth#comment142244_53600) the [article](http://ohr.edu/ask_db/ask_main.php/104/Q1/) where I found this information.

---

* *He thought that Phlimo was joking.*

Comment: So, what was the p'sak for tefillin?

Comment: I'm not sure, @NoachmiFrankfurt.

Comment: No mention of separating because I imagine that wasn't yet possible in the times of the talmud! However maybe wikipedia could prove me wrong...